# Trailing thanks in questions

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, asking-questions

When reviewing questions from new users I often encounter they postfix their questions with "Thanks in advance", "Thank you", "Thanks, %name%", whatever. Is thanking in **questions** appropriate or should it be removed when editing/reviewing?

Comment: See also: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950)

Comment: This was a test, right?

Comment: @icktoofay, afaik, greetings are automatically stripped out of questions. Tried it — http://stackoverflow.com/q/24501971/472695, "Hello" was stripped.

Comment: @modchan: That’s right, and I’m glad it’s there. But that question asked not only about ‘hi’, but also the ‘thanks’ you’re asking about. In short, the consensus is that they *should* be removed, even though trailing ‘thanks’es are not stripped automatically. (I believe they had concerns about false positives.)

Comment: @icktoofay, yup, question is large enough and it was easy to miss that part of discussion. Okay, I've now got reference for future actions.

Comment: @brasofilo, yep, it was testing sense of humour. You didn't pass.