# "Chatty" flag declined on comment but I think that was the wrong decision

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, etiquette

[I flagged a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/542251) on this answer:

[Recover dropped stash in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91795/542251)

As too chatty, basically because all the comments are `Thanks this help load`, `you saved my day`, etc. These slightly useless and heavily upvoted comments push more useful comments, that add to the question, further down.

But rather than cleaning up all the chatty comments, which is what I hoped would happen, it was declined. :(

Based on these meta questions:

[Trailing thanks in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262087/trailing-thanks-in-questions)

[Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)

I think that declining that flag was wrong.

So who's right? Should these comments be removed or not? I don't want to be a kill joy and remove all comments where people want to say *thank you*, but this answer has **10** thank you comments on it!!

Comment: Did you individually flag all those comments? Or made one flag requesting cleanup?

Comment: One flagged on one comment, I didn't want to create duplicate flags.

Comment: So, anyone any thoughts on what I should do here? Reflag it? Just forget it and get drunk?

Comment: @Liam I would wait for an answer on this question.

Comment: That's an old question.  I'm not so sure that cleaning up ancient comments is at the top of the moderators' priority list.  Your flag is accurate, but perhaps not very welcome.

Comment: I don't think the age of the comments should have any bearing on it. OP gave a good reason for them to be nuked.

Comment: It seems quite possible that the old fawning comments encourage new ones: look at the repetition (you saved my lunchbreak).

Comment: Delete them all. We certainly don't want to allow any courtesy or friendly exchange in SO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flagging the answer/question with the custom flag: "There are a lot of chatty comments here ("Thanks", etc.)." is what I do in those cases. Those flags have always been marked helpful and the comments removed.