# Failed audit question

Tags: support, review-suspension

I failed an audit, for reasons that I now understand.  However, I got hit with "YOU FAILED THE AUDIT", and am blocked from reviewing for two days, even though I've passed all of the recent tests I can recall.  Can someone please explain why I'm suspended from reviewing?

Comment: You should have voted to close the question.  You did not.  You flag posts for editing if they're acceptable posts that could just use a bit of help making them better.

Comment: You took the wrong action. Consider reading [How do I deal with non-English content?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/2607247) From there, you should see what the correct action would have been.

Comment: That's fair, but why would I lose review privileges when I've not failed another audit recently that I can recall?

Comment: @betseyb Either you *have* failed other audits recently and don't remember, or a mod banned you manually because they noticed you reviewing incorrectly.  Since you say you saw the failed audit warning immediately upon taking action, it would apparently be the former.

Comment: @betseyb: [Explanation on automatic review bans.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/2675154)

Comment: see also: [Triage Review Queue - Inconsistent guidelines for “Requires Editing”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing)

Comment: Side note: you may want to review policy on adding "Thanks" to the posts - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262087/trailing-thanks-in-questions

Comment: @gnat I agree it's probably a duplicate, but how do you know the OP failed an audit in the *Triage* review queue?

Comment: @Glorfindel - See the link in my answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel [original revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/342698/1) of this question mentioned action "needs editing", this option is available only in [meta-tag:triage]

Comment: Thanks, it couldn't be deduced from the current state of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[That post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15060346) was spam:

[image: Review question]

The text, in a rough translation, stated something about boosting the SEO of websites, followed by the link to his site. We've had a lot of non-English spam like this, with nonsense text followed by a link, so you want to be careful when reviewing this.

Even if you did want to edit this, check the translation first to make sure it makes sense and the question is worth editing. A random question about boosting SEO for websites would not be on topic here, even after an edit.

As for why you were banned, audit failures on clear spam I believe can carry an immediate ban. It doesn't matter if you had passed other audits. Also, the system may have picked up on your recent review activity: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269260/betseyb?tab=activity&sort=all&page=1 where you only chose that action, and did so very rapidly. That looks highly suspicious, and is a good indicator that someone is not reviewing correctly.

Comment: @betseyb Had you simply voted to close the question, rather than marking it as spam, you still would have passed the audit.

Comment: I admit to misunderstanding the intent of 'needs editing'.  I've read the pointers to the guidelines, and look forward to making higher quality reviews in the future.